# How did the Telstar 525/405-line conversion system from 1962 work?

Tags: signal-processing, tv

[The Wikipedia article on the Telstar satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telstar) from the early 1960s says that in order to facilitate transatlantic television signals (where the US had the 525-line (480 visible) NTSC system, and the UK's BBC had a 405-line system) the BBC had room-filling video signal conversion apparatus.

> The standards 525/405 conversion equipment (filling a large room) was researched and developed by the BBC and located in the BBC Television Centre, London

I'm curious how this conversion equipment setup worked. I know that [delay-lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_delay_line)
  are used in relatively modern analog television systems (such as PAL), but it's implied a delay-line system could really only buffer a single line - rather than multiple entire frames to cover a frame-rate mismatch.

Today, to convert video of one-frame-rate and resolution to another necessarily involves modern interpolation algorithms operating on multiple digital frame-buffers - but [Wikipedia implies that the [capability for video framebuffers in the 1960s simply didn't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer#History). I know that but it wasn't feasible to bufferm

(I'm *assuming* that they had a fully electronic system and that they weren't employing tricks such as using a 525-line TV-signal projector to illuminate a screen that was being simultaneously filmed by a 405-line camera for onward distribution.)

My question is: how could an electronic television signal frame-rate-and-resolution conversion system be implemented using 1960s-era technology?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1960's standards convertors did involve CRTs and cameras, with quite a lot of tweaking to minimise artefacts.
This description of the [state of the art](https://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/publications/bbc_monograph_55) at the time, from BBC Engineering, goes into a lot of detail about the process.

Quartz crystals used as delay lines were just around the corner. By 1970 the BBC had built an entire [field store based convertor](https://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/publications/rdreport_1970_37) that way. THe references in the linked report show that the design process was already under way in 1964.

[image]
Quite a substantial piece of equipment. (picture from RD Report 1970/37 linked above)

Comment: Wow! Thank you :D

Comment: Substantial??  Heck, that's barely a minicomputer!

Comment: @HotLicks It's very substantial by today's standards!